# Conditional matrix normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability, matrix, conditioning

Suppose $\epsilon$ is a $n\times p$ with independent rows $\epsilon_i\sim N(0, \Sigma)$. $Y$ is a matrix of size $n\times p_1$ and $X$ a matrix of size $n\times p_2$ constructed as
$$
Y=XA+\epsilon B\\
X=\epsilon C,
$$
where $A,B,C$ are matrices of conformable sizes.

My problem is: what is the distribution of $Y|X$?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?